# Laravel 5.2 : MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219 - updating the forms

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have a form and i am trying to update the forms. In the form, 'name' is a unique field (added the unique condition in request page and in a table, name is set as unique). when i try to update the form (i provided the value, the is already exist in the table), it shows 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219' error.

If i am update the 'name' with non-existing name that is not in table, it will work without any issues.

[image: Error]

Router

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['superadmin']], function () {
    Route::post('/sadmin/update_club',array('uses' => 'SAdmin\ClubController@updateClub', 'as' => 'updateClub'));
}
```

Request

```
class UpdateClubRequest extends Request
{    
   public function authorize()
   {
      return true;
   }
   public function rules()
   {
     return [
        'name' => 'required|max:150|unique:clubs,name,'.Request::input('id'),
        'logo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,bmp,gif,svg|max:10000',
      ];
   }
 }
```

Layout Page

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'updateClub', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files'=>true)) }}

  {{ Form::hidden('id', $club[0]['id']) }}
  {{ Form::text('name', $club[0]['name'], array('class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => 50)) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: I feel `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is typically related to `posting` to a `get` route or vice versa, which is what the error message shows as well. By chance do you have a `get` route defined to the same location _above_ your `post` route?

Comment: @camelCase . yes i have lot of get route...          
        Route::get('/sadmin/clubs', 'SAdmin\ClubController@Clubs');
        Route::get('/sadmin/add_club', 'SAdmin\ClubController@addClub');

Comment: But any to `'/sadmin/update_club'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any error here so it's possible error might be somewhere else. I see for example that you are using `superadmin` for this route. You should run in console:

```
php artisan route:list
```

to see what middlewares are applied to `updateClub` route name and verify this middlewares code because it's possible that some of them is making incorrect redirection (method `GET` to route that has only `POST` for example).

The second thing (it's not causing problem here but you should follow some standards) - if you create action that updates something, you should use `PUT` method (POST is for creating new objects), so in both route and form for this route you should change POST into PUT

**EDIT**

The problem could be also a bit different. Let's assume you have multi-step form (probably this is your case because you are using POST only for , so you are using the following methods GET (step1) -> POST (step2) -> POST (step3). So now, if in step2 you get error, Request class will try to make redirection again to step2 but with GET method, so you should in routes.php allow also `GET` method, so in your case you should probably change

```
Route::post('someroute' ...
```

into:

```
Route::match(['get','post'], 'someroute' ...
```

You should do it for page for which you are displaying this form

Comment: Actually this problem exist only if i am adding the name that is already exist in table. if i am changing the request - " 'name'=> 'required|unique:clubs,name,'.Request::input('id') "  to " 'name'=> 'required' ", it will work

Comment: @LindoSebastian But have you changed it for route you are displaying the form? Show the route in routes.php on which you are displaying this form

Comment: @LindoSebastian Glad I was able to help